# Search Google Maps Box without Places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

If I subscribed Google Maps API, but not Google Places API, is it possible however to find a *location point* from a *search term*?

Something similar to [this CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYjJqO?editors=101) (using places)

```js
(function() {

  var marker;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('search');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', updateMap);

  function updateMap() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    var place = places[0];
    var radius = 1000000;

    if (marker) { marker.setMap(null); }

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map, title: place.name,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: marker.position, radius: radius
    });
    map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
  }
})();
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Here">
<h2/>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) for that purpose:

> The Google Maps API provides a geocoder class for geocoding and
>   reverse geocoding dynamically from user input.

**Example**

```js
function initMap() {

    var marker;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var btnSearch = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
    addEvent(btnSearch, 'click', function () {
        var input = document.getElementById('search');
        updateMap(map, input.value);
    });
}



function updateMap(map, address) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                //console.log(results[0].geometry.location);

                var result = results[0];
                var radius = 1000000;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    title: result.formatted_address,
                    position: result.geometry.location
                });

                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: marker.position,
                    radius: radius
                });
                map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());

            }
            else {
                console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
            }
        });
    }


}


function addEvent(element, evnt, funct) {
    if (element.attachEvent)
        return element.attachEvent('on' + evnt, funct);
    else
        return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
}
```

```css
#map{
     width: 640px;
     height: 480px;
}
```

```html
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Here">
  <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
  <h2 />
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
                async defer></script>
```